# Creating an executable file to run MATLAB codes and shell scripts along with a database connection

Tags: windows, matlab, shell, exe, matlab-figure

Can someone please help me out in building a **stand-alone application** (executable file) that will be able to run MATLAB codes and Shell scripts (in Cygwin) on Windows. I will further require it to extract information from a database in my exe file.
Is there an easy way to create .exe files without a lot of coding from scratch? Just like building MATLAB GUIs? Also, how am I supposed to import programs packages into these files?

Answer (score 0):

All of your questions can be answered with `deploytool`. [Here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/), you'll find an overview of the tool. I've done what you're trying to do, included the inclusion of packages, with this tool, and found it fairly simple. It does, however, require the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/), which I understand is quite expensive. I found that my development machine at work already had the compiler, so you may have it and not even know it. If you don't have it, and aren't willing to buy it, this is a pretty hard problem to solve. To test if you have it, just type `deploytool` into your MATLAB command line. If it works, you have the compiler.